# Blocking popups and ads

Tags: chromium, privacy

I'm having a fight with ads, popups and tracking cookies. But I'm having some issues.

Software used:

- Chromium 18.0.1025.168

Extensions used:

- Adblock Plus (Beta)1.2
- AdBlock+ Element Hiding Helper1.1.9.18
- Better Pop Up Blocker2.1.6
- Ghostery3.0.0

With this configuration, I'm always getting this error:

```
    Warning:
This extension failed to modify a network request because the modification conflicted with another extension.
```

I know if I disable "better popup", this goes away. It's perfectly normal, due to those extensions trying to block the same things. Problem is, I can't live without all of them!
Can anyone advise me about some good configuration?

- Can't live without adblock plus, because I hate ads.
- Better popup blocker is essential too (believe me, chrome doesn't block a lot of popups, and I have a website or 2 that can prove that.)
- And ghostery is a must... I can't bare the idea of being tracked all the time by some companies.

So I'm kinda lost here! everything is needed, but they conflict with each other. I mean, it has to exist a perfect combination out there, I know I'm not the only one hating the privacy issues nowadays! I am really thankful for any tips guys.

Comment: Have you looked at Dansguardian  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DansGuardian

Comment: hum, thanks man, i'll look at it. In the meantime, i removed "betterpopup blocker" and installed 2 more extensions: Poper Blocker1.27 and Flash blocker. apparently, they all doing well with each other :D

Comment: hum, i got the conflict again. I've been told its a conflict mainly between adblock plus and ghostery. since they are both vital to me, i'll live with that

Comment: Just use AdBlock Plus

Comment: Ghostery doesn't just block trackers; ghostery also blocks ads.

Answer (score 1):

Well, on Google Chrome (proprietary version of Chromium) I use a combination of:

- [Adblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)
- [Keep MORE opts out](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eoibfeagdaaoimfpfalgbmmegagdconp?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)
- And Better Popup Blocker :)

Always works, no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Javascript selective blocker plugin, like [ScriptNo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf) or NotScript. Then you could whitelist secure sites, blocking anything else (popups and tracking sites included).