# How to block ads on Google Chrome using Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I have installed ad blockers (as suggested, [Blocking popups and ads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160612/blocking-popups-and-ads)) which blocks ad only on YouTube.
Whenever I open a link, for instance https://www..com/jobs/jobs-categories/education-training.aspx, Then I got numerous ads as well.

How do I stop these unwanted ads?

Comment: I have already installed these ad-blockers, but only works for You Tube.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the ilmkidunya website. Ghostery blocks some of the ads. The google adsense ads are blocked. Not all ads are blocked because it looks like some of the ads are provided by the actual webpage instead of third party advertisers. Ghostery works on almost all webpages. You can view the page source here: `view-source:https://www.ilmkidunya.com/jobs/jobs-categories/education-training.aspx`

Comment: These ads are not blocked because, if you press CTRL+SHIFT+C you can move your mouse over the ads and you will see in the alt src= that the ads are provided by the ilmkidunya parent URL. This is why the ads are not blocked because the ads are actually provided by the same URL.

Comment: However, stackoverflow ads are blocked on stackoverflow so maybe I don't know?

Comment: Thank you @mchid